# intellij module/project with android and java sources

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am having an annoying problem with organising my sources. We have a client server application with the server written in java and android as the client. The repository contains all the server files in one folder and all the android specific stuff in another at the top level.The Android folder however is not complete since it needs some files that exist in the server folder. I need a way to pull down the all the necessary files from 2 separate folders in my repo all in to one Intellij module/project.

My colleagues using eclipse were able to solve this by creating an android project, downloading the android source files from the repo and then using the add to build path > link source feature. This created symbolic links in the android project to the necessary files in the server folder so that android could compile.

How do i achieve this in Intellij? I hope this is clear but it is quite hard to explain. Thanks.

Also if this matters i am using SVN.

Comment: Use **Add Content Root** button in the `Project Structure` | `Sources` tab for the module. Then mark appropriate folders as Source.